# Creating as many processes you want with Fork()

Tags: c

I'm trying to get my head around the system call fork() and I'd like to create as many grandchild processes as I'd like. Basically all I want to achieve is:

1 parent process with -> 2 child processes -> each child -> has two child processes (which are a total of 4 grandchild processes from the parent).

```
              parent
          /           \
         /             \
    child1             child2
    /    \               /  \
   /      \             /    \
  /        \           /      \
g.child1  g.child2  g.child3  g.child4
```

So far I can get 3 out of the 4 grandchild but I'm also getting a new child from one of the grandchilds. This is the output I'm getting so far:

```
Process Pid: 5960 PPid: 5958 (position: 1).
Process Pid: 5959 PPid: 5958 (position: 0).
Process Pid: 5962 PPid: 5959 (position: 0).
Process Pid: 5961 PPid: 5960 (position: 1).
Process Pid: 5963 PPid: 5961 (position: 1).
Process Pid: 5964 PPid: 5960 (position: 1).
```

Any tips?

Thank you

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define NUM_HIJOS 2 

void lanzanieto(int i)
{
    int proceso;

    proceso = fork();
        if (proceso > 0) {
                wait(NULL);
        } else if (proceso == 0) {
            printf("Process Pid: %d PPid: %d (position: %d).\n",getpid(),getppid(), i);
        } else if (proceso == -1) {
            perror("fallo en fork");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
}
int main(void)
{
    int proceso, i;

    for (i=0; i<NUM_HIJOS; i++) {
        proceso = fork();

        if (proceso == 0) {

            switch(i) {
                case 0:
                    printf("Process Pid: %d PPid: %d (position: %d).\n",getpid(),getppid(), i);
                    lanzanieto(i);
                    exit(0);
                case 1:
                    printf("Process Pid: %d PPid: %d (position: %d).\n",getpid(),getppid(), i);
                    lanzanieto(i);
                    lanzanieto(i);
                    exit(0);        
            }

        }  else if (proceso == -1) {
            perror("fallo en fork");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

    }
    proceso = wait(NULL);
    while (proceso > 0) {
        proceso = wait(NULL);
    }
    /* ************************************* */
    if (proceso == -1 && errno != ECHILD) {
        perror("fallo en wait");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you identify the process hierarchy tree? Please post the output.

Comment: I have not yet, I'm still trying to find out how to do all 4 grandchild first. Once I get it I will go with the position Id number.

Comment: the posted code logic is not correct for what you are trying to perform.  strongly suggest modifying the code to be 'direct' about what it wants to do, rather than twiddling with a loop counter, various calls to `exit()` and various calls to `lanzanieto()`.  In the end, the 'direct' approach will work much better.

Comment: the posted code is using a 'int' as the type returned from fork(), however it actually returns a 'pid_t'.  Note: the 'pid_t' is defined in unistd.h.

Answer (score 4):

## Concept

Firstly, create a `fork()` will look like this :

```
id = fork(); 
if (id < 0) {
    /* error */
    exit(1);
} 
else if (i > 0) { /* Parent > 0 */
    /* parent logic */
} 
else { /* Child = 0 */
    /* child logic */
}
```

`fork()` will create a child process along side the parent process.

Therefore, if you want to match your tree (and based on your existing code), the process diagram will look like :

```
parent : fork()
           |--> parent : fork()
           |               |--> parent
           |               |--> child_2
           |
           |--> child_1 : fork()
                           |--> child_1
                           |--> sub_child_1
```

To put it simply, you have to recursively `fork()` inside the parent and every new child process.

However acknowledge that forking process that way aren't nice looking.

It could be better to have a function, let's say `create_child()`, which fork only from the parent :

```
parent : create_fork()
               |--> parent : create_child()
               |        |
               |        |--> parent : create_child()
               |        |      |
               |        |      |--> parent 
               |        |      |--> child_3 : do_whatever()
               |        |
               |        |--> child_2 : do_whatever()
               |        
               |--> child_1 : do_whatever()
```

## Solution

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void print_pid(char *proc_name)
{
    printf("%s: %d\n", proc_name, getpid());
}

int create_child(void)
{
    pid_t child_pid = fork();
    if (child_pid == 0)
    {
        print_pid("child");
    }
    else if (child_pid < 0)
    {
        perror("create_child");
    }
    return (child_pid);
}

int make_babies(int babies_number)
{
    /* if no baby */
    if (babies_number <= 0)
        return 0;

    /* if baby(ies) */
    pid_t child_pid = create_child();
    if (child_pid > 0)
    {
        make_babies(babies_number - 1);
        waitpid(child_pid, NULL, 0);
    }
    return child_pid;
}

int main(void)
{
    print_pid("parent");
    make_babies(50);
    return errno;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but what you suggest is what I'm doing but instead of an "if" I use a switch and a function to launch childs (lanzanieto(i)).

Comment: I've added the solution.

Comment: Thanks you Valentin, I followed your recommendation and I did so. You can see the final result in another thread that I open with new doubts.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33804467/how-to-count-the-fork-processes-position/33805716?noredirect=1#comment55381314_33805716

Comment: If it fits your need it's ok. Consider validating the solution in order to close the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You must remember that both the child process and the parent process continue executing the same code. When you call `lanzanieto(i)` twice in `case 1:` in `main()`, both the parent and the child from the first call to `lanzanieto(i)` (which are the child and grandchild of the original parent) continue on to the second call to `lanzanieto(i)`, so both produce another child.

Comment: I see your point but how do you suggest me to kill that extra process?

Comment: @krm76 You don't kill it; you must make sure not to create it. In `lanzanieto()` you know whether you are the parent or child by the return value from the `fork` so you can decide what to do. (In `main` I see you use `exit(0)` in the child to avoid continuing -- you could do something similar in `lanzanieto()`.